# mv command with a wrong name that has brackets

Tags: bash, shell, mv

I was renaming a batch of files and forgot the file extension. Tried to add it back with the following command and the files disappeared.

```
for i in S02*; do mv "$i" "$(i).mkv";done
```

Bash gave the error: "i: command not found". Guessing I shouldn't have included the brackets. Any idea where I can find my files now?

Thanks!

Comment: This is why I do most batch work by constructing and echoing the commands, then piping the result through a shell if I like what I see (`do echo mv etc.`, then add on a `|sh -x` when it's working).

Answer (score 2):

Your files are gone and can probably not be recovered unless backup was taken. You should have used curly braces `{}` and not parens `()`:

```
for i in S02*; do mv "$i" "${i}.mkv";done
```

`$()` is used for command substitution. Since `i` is not a command, the error you got was the correct one. However, that command got substituted with nothing so all your files were clobbered.

Comment: Not all files are gone: the last one in the S02* set of files is now named ".mkv".  Try: "ls -l .mkv".  
I know, small comfort if all the other S02* files are gone!